# Example of stress or tone on a consonant

Tags: tones, orthography

Wondering if there is such thing as [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) on a consonant, e.g. `t́`, `ĺ`, `ḿ`, `ś`, `ʃ́`... If so, what the example language would be. I haven't seen any on Wikipedia.

Same thing for [tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)), I haven't seen any tones specified for consonants, only vowels. So using pinyin, maybe like `ť`, `š`...

Comment: Consider post it on linguistics.stackexchange.com not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the character 呣 for instance, we can have things like:

- m̄

> 叹词, 表示疑问。如：呣, 你说什么？(汉语大词典)

- ḿ

> 歎詞﹐用法同嗯﹐表示疑問﹑不以為然或出乎意外：呣﹐他去幹甚麼？(Longman’s)

- m̀

> 歎詞﹐用法同嗯﹐表示答應﹑應諾：呣﹐我這就去。(Longman’s)

There is also record of a *neutral* toned 呣:

- m

> 叹词, 表示应诺。如：呣, 我知道了。(汉语大词典)

——

嗯 similarly can give us things like:

- ń
- ň
- ǹ

Comment: I would like to add on to this by saying that nasal sounds consonants are the only ones with these stressed tones.

Comment: Also, if someone is concerned that these syllables are only "marginal" in Mandarin phonology, there are more examples in Shanghainese. 无 is, I believe, also a syllabic m (with associated tone). 是 is phonetically a syllabic z, but phonologically might be analyzed differently. In any event, tones can only be attached to syllables, so most consonants won't have an attached tone.

Comment: m/ng is also prevalent in Cantonese.